# webkit/webkit.h: No such file or directory

Tags: webkit, vala

I am trying to create Vala program with WebKit. 
Here is how I compile it:

```
valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg granite --pkg glib-2.0 --pkg webkitgtk-3.0  <filenames>
```

and in one file I included WebKit:

```
using WebKit;
```

The compiler says:

```
fatal error: webkit/webkit.h: No such file or directory
#include <webkit/webkit.h>
```

I heard that this file should be in /usr/include/webkit/webkit.h, but it isn't there.

I'm using elementary OS Freya x64.

Can you tell me which packages I need to install or what else I need to do? I already have libwebkitgtk-3.0-0, libwebkitgtk-3.0-common and libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think I figured it out. I have somehow disabled Ubuntu main repository and apt-get was trying to download libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev from ppa:webkit-team, where it has version 1.8 and was not compatible with my other packages. Enabling main repository and removing ppa:webkit-team fixed this.

Answer (score 3):

You also need `libwebkitgtk-dev`. In general, you're always going to need a corresponding `-dev` package for each of the `--pkg` options.

Comment: I tried this and got that: Package libwebkitgtk-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libwebkitgtk-dev' has no installation candidat

Comment: elementary OS is based on Ubuntu and should have the corresponding package, you should check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and make sure that you have run `apt-get update` after that.

Comment: There's also a `libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev`. Just search for `webkit dev` in Aptitude and browse.

Comment: @apmasell same as previous.

Comment: @apmasell tried to dl libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev from Ubuntu website and install it and that's what I got:  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev:
 libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev depends on libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 (= 2.4.4-1~ubuntu1); however:Version of libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 on system is 2.4.0-1ubuntu2.libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev depends on libwebkitgtk-common-dev (= 2.4.4-1~ubuntu1);however: Package libwebkitgtk-common-dev is not installed. libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev depends on libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-dev (= 2.4.4-1~ubuntu1); however: Package libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-dev is not installed.

Comment: What do you mean “dl”? Did you use `apt-get`? It sounds like your package configuration is broken. I would consult with the Elementary OS folks.

Comment: @apmasell no, I meant I downloaded it from there: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/trusty/libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev

Comment: You need to also get that package's dependencies. That's what `apt-get` is supposed to do for you.